# Is there a native linux application that can interface with mint.com?

Tags: linux, finance

Is there a native Linux application that can interface with mint.com?  I like the website, but I would also like to have that information stored locally so I can view it anytime, even if I am not online.  Also, is there anyway I can just bypass mint.com altogether and enter in all of my accounts directly and have it periodically update their information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Mint.com is [focusing](http://satisfaction.mint.com/mint/topics/desktop_application-1fcwrp) on mobile devices rather than desktop application.

Comment: Presumably you could run the Android emulator under Linux and use Mint locally that way ... maybe not practical though.

Comment: Aside from mint.com, is there any other way to connect to your bank accounts?  There must be an open API for banks to communicate, but is that API available for single users?